# Creating new datastore and VMFS

Tags: virtualization, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, vmfs

I was currently working on the ESXi lab and trying to do some work with it. So I have an ESXi that is running on a server and I installed 2 ESXi on it (two ESXi are running on the primary ESXi).
The problem is after finishing installing 2 ESXi, none of them had a datastore. So I had to create a new VMFS.
But I faced this problem:
There is no device in the list so I can create anything!
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You are running 2 nested ESXi on top of your main ESXi server. Add a VMDK to each ESXi VM and then you will be able to create VMFS datastore. There are nested ESXi appliances, which can make deployment easier:

http://vmwa.re/nestedesxi

In addition, the following article should help:

https://www.vmwareblog.org/nested-virtualization-vmware-esxi-vs-microsoft-hyper-v/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, It was because of the conflict version.
My main ESXi version was 6.7 and the two other ESXis were 7.
So after I installed version 6.7 instead of 7, the problem was gone!